# Вывод русского языка PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.x, pyqt4

Собственно выводится как на картинке, нужно что бы выводилось на русском. строки берутся из базы данных

```
for row in data.data:
    self.table.setItem(x, 0, QTableWidgetItem(row[0].encode('utf-8')))
    self.table.setItem(x, 1, QTableWidgetItem(row[1].encode('utf-8')))
    self.table.setItem(x, 2, QTableWidgetItem(row[2].encode('utf-8')))
    self.table.setItem(x, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[3])))
    self.table.setItem(x, 4, QTableWidgetItem(str(data.get_age(row[3]))))
    self.table.setItem(x, 5, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[4])))
    self.table.setItem(x, 6, QTableWidgetItem(row[5].encode('utf-8')))
    self.table.setItem(x, 7, QTableWidgetItem(row[6].encode('utf-8')))
    self.table.setItem(x, 8, QTableWidgetItem(row[7].encode('utf-8')))
    x += 1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В базе в какой кодировке хранятся данные?

Comment: Хранится в unicode

Answer (score 0):

Надо было удалить encode('utf-8'). Понятия не имею почему он не хотел сначала без него работать

Comment: Потому что надо разобраться в строковых типах, что такое `str`, что такое `unicode`, и вычитать в документациях, какие функции какой тип ожидают :)